# Django i18n localizes project partly

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Finished localization of Django project, performed makemessages and compilemessages.
Inspecting effect, I realized that only 10 % of whole project is localized successfully.

```
#: .\account.html.py:100
msgid "Old password"
msgstr "Старый пароль"

#: .\account.html.py:101
msgid "New password"
msgstr "Новый пароль"

#: .\account.html.py:102
msgid "Confirm new password"
msgstr "Подтвердите новый пароль"
```

So, for example, if first two lines are localized properly, for third localization doesn't  happen at all, even if there's no difference.
Maybe, someone could explain why is that and can give me some info about i18n methods?

Comment: Do you have #fuzzy tags above the `msgid` - if you have, you should remove them.

Comment: As you can see, I don't have them.

Comment: No errors during ``compilemessages``?

Comment: I solved it by writing LOCALE_PATHS = (PROJECT_PATH, 'locale') in settings.py.
And rewriting localization once again, just in case.

***Explicit is better than implicit.***